# shift /var/lib to a new partition

Tags: mount

I have a system which completely resides on a (relatively small) single harddrive (/dev/sda). Now I am expecting to /var/lib/ to become populated with more and more files (due to using lxd containers) and therefore I want to shift that to another hard drive or partition which I am adding to the system.

2 methods come to mind and I'd like to get some advice from a little more experienced people which one to favor

**METHOD A - symlink**

1. sudo cp -a -r /var/lib/ /mnt/new-hd/
2. sudo mv /var/lib /var/old-lib
3. sudo ln -s /mnt/new-hd/lib
4. reboot

**METHOD B - mounting new folder over existing /var/lib**

1. sudo mnt /dev/new-hd
2. /mnt/temp sudo
3. cp -a -r /var/lib/* /mnt/temp
4. sudo umount /mnt/temp
5. create fstab entry for /dev/new-hd (to be mounted to /var/lib)
6. sudo mount -a

looking at it now. I'm in favor of **METHOD B** slightly. Any comments?

In my usecase it's about lxd, so I am also wondering whether shifting the entire /var/lib is the best choice for this or should I only move the relevant parts? Mocing the entire /var/lib has the advantage to have a structure which is very similar to the default (and therefore less custom things to be aware of)

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/691039/adding-a-shared-host-directory-to-an-lxc-lxd-container

Comment: Also related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/833267/lxd-moving-containers-snapshots-to-another-drive

Comment: method c:
1. turn off power
2. conect hdd to another pc/laptop (or run any live-usb/cd version of linux)
3 . move the /var/lib to another location
4. update /etc/fstab
5. connect hdd 
6. turn pc/;aptop on

Answer (score 1):

If you were building the system from scratch, you'd probably use method B because that's the proper way to spread your file system over multiple physical devices. So if you can do B, I think thats the more-sound approach. I'd only use method A if you were planning to exchange different copies frequently, or needed one copy to exist in two places.

Comment: ok, seems you both agree on that. And that sounds reasonable to me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is it really necessary to perform this operation on a running machine? Why dont you download a livecd of any linux distro, and run the system from cd/usb?
You should be able to move the /var/lib to any other location without any problem. Dont forgett to copy/move file permissions.

Comment: no, not necessary to do this on a running system at all. would you then just mv /var/lib to the right place? I mean 'mv', not 'cp'

Comment: yes. boot from a cd, move the /var/lib to the desired destination. The advantage of this is - if anything goes wrong (like wrong permissions) - you will still be able to reboot, start the livecd linux and correct the settings. This is rather simple operation, but sometimes there is little devil hidden in "simple task" ;) 
Remeber to check permision on /var/lib after you mout the additional drive.